# Error mouse: not useable (blocked) on executing sikuli automation script remotely

Tags: java, sikuli

we have two servers, say server A and server B (Windows). I am executing a skuli script present in server B from server A using power shell script:

$scriptblock = {
D:
cd ssedesktopautomation
mvn test -Dtest="AexeoTest#aexeoreporter_test"
}

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerB -ScriptBlock $scriptblock

but i am  getting error:

[error] Mouse: not useable (blocked)

Note: Both server A and server B is in running state (with screen open)

when executed from a sikuli script remotely, it should be identifying images and perform the actions on target server since as I have that remote server opened using Remote Desktop Connection